# Unit test not showing as covering method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

In one of my unit test classes, I'm doing several tests that test the response of a method. They're very similar tests, so I've created a private method to avoid writing out basically the same test multiple times (I'm lazy).

The problem is, in Visual Studio, the "passing" information above the method itself isn't showing the coverage from those unit tests that call the private method.

**Example method**

[image: Simple example method]

**Example unit tests**

[image]

As you can see, the unit tests all call MethodForTesting1, though only the first unit test, the one that calls it directly, is seen to cover the method.

Is there any way around this, or do the Visual Studio testing tools just not like private methods in unit tests?

**EDIT**
Quick addition, I'm new to unit testing, so for bonus points, is there a better way to gauge code coverage when looking through a class?

**EDIT 2**
To address those quick answers who points out that I forgot the `[TestMethod]` above the last method, it still doesn't show code coverage

[image]

Comment: The method for testing is actually only being directly called/referenced in two place as the code correctly indicates. the first test method and the private one used for DRY. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You could also consider using paramterized or data driven unit tests. which would reduce the test methods down to one that just takes the different cases you want to test and seems to apply to this particular problem

Comment: @Nkosi The ultimate goal is actually to figure out why the "passing" reference above the function doesn't include the unit tests that call a private test. After reading around, I understand now that a private method with asserts isn't the best way to go, but the original code all works fine. I suppose you could say the ultimate goal was to sate my curiosity.

Comment: Ok noted. For this scenario you should look into Data Driven Tests

Comment: @Nkosi Great, thanks. I'll give those a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, your unit tests should be written as below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod21()
    {
        Class1 cls = new Class1();
        Assert.AreEqual("Jackie", cls.GetNewName("Jack"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod31()
    {
        Class1 cls = new Class1();
        Assert.AreEqual("Johnny", cls.GetNewName("John"));
    }
```

You should not use common private method like Verify_MethodForTesting_EchosString(string testString) containing Assert from different test methods - that's not best practice. Your test cases are not easy to understand.

Also creation of object should be done for each test method - cft = new ClassForTesting(), when tests are run in parallel, shared object may create problem.

For code coverage, you should use Tool as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested) (available for VS Enterprise edition). Also some information here in this [article](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/06/18/understanding-code-coverage-how-to-determine-which-portion-of-code-is-being-tested-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: So unit tests don't necessarily adhere to the DRY principle? And I don't have access to Enterprise edition, only Professional, but I'll give those a read, thank you

Comment: Yes correct. When a test fails, you want to understand what went wrong.  You thus want a test where all setup logic reveals itself to you at a glance. So each unit test should have its own setup / tear down logic (setting up variables, properties etc). Check out this [article](https://stackify.com/unit-testing-basics-best-practices/)

Comment: @DarkHippo DRY isn't all that relevant to unit tests as it is to your source code. You shouldn't test the same scenario more than once (like in the tests above). You'll probably want to assert that a certain value is equal to what you would expect and that the right exception is thrown when wrong args were passed and so on. Check this [article](https://www.typemock.com/unit-test-patterns-for-net-part-i) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the

```
[TestMethod]
```

annotation above your last test methode.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mark it as a test method. Try adding the corresponding attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
public object MethodForTesting1()
{
  ...
```

Comment: So you're saying I have to mark the method that I'm testing as a test method? But it's not a test method, it's the method that is being tested.